# Wait for only one task to complete

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Let's say I have two tasks, with the following requirements:

1. Both are asynchronous.
2. Both run in parallel
3. The moment one of them completes I need to know which one did.

I came up with the following code, but it just hangs after both tasks get started (the WaitAny function never returns).  I am also getting a squiggly line under Run function telling me to add await inside it, but VS complains when I try to add it in front of Task.WaitAny.  Should I be wrapping WaitAny in another Task?  What am I doing wrong?

```
async void Run()
{
    Task task1 = Task1();
    Task task2 = Task2();

    int completedTaskIdx = Task.WaitAny(task1, task2);

    Debug.WriteLine("completedTaskIdx = {0}", completedTaskIdx.ToString());
}

async Task Task1()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Task 1 Start");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Debug.WriteLine("Task 1 Stop");
}

async Task Task2()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Task 2 Start");
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    Debug.WriteLine("Task 2 Stop");
}
```

Comment: @Eser I did look at it, but it doesn't return index of the completed task.

Comment: @Eternal21 Your requirement 3. did not say you needed to know the index of the completed task, just which tasks was the one that completed. It does do that by returning the completed task.

Comment: The compiler warning is telling you to get rid of the `async` keyword because you never used `await` in the code. You have no place to use `await` inside of your code because you do not use any methods that return a `Task` to do your waiting with (You would need to switch to `WhenAny` instead of `WaitAny` to get a task you could await). Note: getting rid of the `async` keyword will not fix your problem, just get rid of the compiler warning.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I do not care about index, just the completed task.  I didn't realize WhenAny returns completed task, I figured it returns another 'compound' task that needs to be awaited.  Your answer cleared it up for me now.  I've just started using Tasks, and despite reading a ton about them, I'm still learning.  Thanks.

Comment: @Eternal21 it does not return the completed task, it returns a `Task<Task>` where the `.Result` will be the completed task. That is why you await the `WhenAny` then you await the result again to await the finished task.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain man these tasks are really confusing.  I'm still not clear how does the second await go around the issue of the task finishing in an exception.

Comment: The `Task<Task>` returned from `WhenAny` is guaranteed never to have `.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted` or `.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled`, even if the inner task that that `WhenAny` will be returning was in one of those two states. To get the exception from q `TaskStatus.Faulted` task (if there was one) or get the result if you had a `Task<TResult>` you must await the `completedTask` task too. That task is guaranteed to have `.IsCompleted  == true` so the `await` will complete synchronously, it will either immediately get the result or throw a exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't block the UI thread when using asnyc/await, [you will cause dedlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Your `WaitAny()` causes you to get a deadlock. Use `WhenAny` instead, you can use `Array.IndexOf(` to translate the returned task back in to the index.

```
async Task Run()
{
    Task task1 = Task1();
    Task task2 = Task2();

    var tasks = new[] {task1, task2};
    Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

    //It is a good idea to await the retuned task, this is the point a execption would
    //be raised if the task finished with a exception.
    await completedTask;

    int completedTaskIdx = Array.IndexOf(tasks, completedTask);

    //.ToString() will cause you to have a bug, you are calling the 
    //wrong overload of WriteLine. The correct overload will call .ToString() for you.
    Debug.WriteLine("completedTaskIdx = {0}", completedTaskIdx); 
}
```

I also fixed a bug in your `Debug.WriteLine(` call, you where calling [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w33ay0x(v=vs.110).aspx) when you wanted [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190153(v=vs.110).aspx). I also replaced your `async void` with `async Task`, [you should never do `asnyc void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) unless you are using it to match a event handler signature.

Comment: Never knew about that WriteLine overload - good to know.  I've just started explicitly calling ToString() on my format parameters, because I read somewhere it prevents unnecessary boxing/unboxing.

Comment: @Eternal21 I would only worry about that if you find a measurable performance problem.